# Human error please help

Tags: opportunity

I accidentally loaded a product under Opportunities which belongs to another client. How can I remove the Product from the Opportunities?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understand your question correctly.

One solution could be to run some anonymous Apex through the [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com). What you really need to do is query the Products you've loaded for that company and find some way of uniquely identifying those particular products. Potentially, the CreatedDate might suffice.

Make sure you're selecting the right products by using the SOQL Query "app" and make certain you're only getting the records you want to delete. That might be something simple like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, AccountName FROM Products WHERE AccountName = 'Universal Containers' AND CreatedDate > 2015-09-21T00:00:00Z AND CreatedDate < 2015-09-21T23:59:59Z
```

Check this, run it and **make sure you're only selecting what you want to delete.**

As long as you're 100% happy with this you could then run a simple anonymous Apex script. Something like:

```
List<Products> p = [SELECT Id, Name, AccountName FROM Products WHERE AccountName = 'Universal Containers' AND CreatedDate > 2015-09-21T00:00:00Z AND CreatedDate < 2015-09-21T23:59:59Z];

delete p;
```

Might do the job.

We don't use the Products object in our org so forgive me if the query is malformed or something!

> I can't stress enough to make sure you're only selecting what you want to delete so double check this.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

@Poet is right.

**OR**
You can do this -

-> Query only and ONLY those products 
(API Name -OpportunityLineItems / Product2 ->Please do mention specific in question)[Here I am considering your product as  "OpportunityLineItems"]

-> Open developer console - Go to "Debug" menu - click on "Open Execute Anonymous Windo" / or press CTRL + E, and write following code in it -

```
List<<OpportunityLineItems>OpportunityLineItems> lstProduct = new List<<OpportunityLineItems>OpportunityLineItems>();

lstProduct=[SELECT Id, Name, FROM OpportunityLineItems WHERE CreatedDate > 2015-09-21T00:00:00Z AND CreatedDate < 2015-09-21T23:59:59Z]; 

//Make sure you update above select Query to fetch only your affecting products


//Now Update your List of Products

for(OpportunityLineItems obj : lstProduct){

    obj=//Your Correct Parent Opportunity record ID
}

update lstProduct;
```

-> Finally, Click on "Execute" button.

-> (Double check you fetched the correct records - Before writing "FOR
   Loop and update statement")